# Thinkster MEAN Stack tutorial

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was doing the thinkster.io tutorial on the MEAN stack and Flapper News. https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/ I stopped just before the section **Beginning Node**. My code was working until the later parts of the first half of the tutorial. I hope someone can help me identify what is wrong, as I am just a beginner to MEAN.

## My `index.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flapper News</title>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <style> .glyphicon-thumbs-up { cursor:pointer } </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="flapperNews">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <ui-view></ui-view>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Flapper News</h1>
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
            ng-click="upvote(post)"></span>
        {{post.upvotes}}
        <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
            <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
                {{post.title}}
            </a>
            <span ng-hide="post.link">
                {{post.title}}
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>

    <form ng-submit="addPost()"
        style="margin-top:30px;">
        <h3>Add a new post</h3>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Title"
                ng-model="theTitle"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Link"
                ng-model="theLink"></input>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
    </form>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h3>
      <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
        {{post.title}}
      </a>
      <span ng-hide="post.link">
        {{post.title}}
      </span>
    </h3>
  </div>

  <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
      ng-click="incrementUpvotes(comment)"></span>
    {{comment.upvotes}} - by {{comment.author}}
    <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
      {{comment.body}}
    </span>
  </div>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

## My `app.js`

```
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']);

app.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/home.html'
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        });
        .state('posts', {
            url: '/posts/{id}',
            templateUrl: '/posts.html',
            controller: 'PostsCtrl'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}])

app.factory('posts', [function(){
    var o = {
        posts: []
    };
    return o;
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope',
'posts',
function($scope, posts){
    $scope.posts = posts.posts;
    $scope.addPost = function(){
        if(!$scope.theTitle || $scope.theTitle === '') { return; }
        $scope.posts.push({
            title: $scope.theTitle,
            link: $scope.theLink,
            upvotes: 0
            comments: [
                {author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0},
                {author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 0}
            ]
        });
        $scope.theTitle = '';
        $scope.theLink = '';
    }
    $scope.upvote = function(post){
        post.upvotes++;
    }
}]);

app.controller('PostsCtrl', [
'$scope',
'$stateParams',
'posts',
function($scope, $stateParams, posts){
    $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];
    $scope.addComment = function(){
        if($scope.body === '') { return; }
        $scope.post.comments.push({
            body: $scope.body,
            author: 'user',
            upvotes: 0
        });
        $scope.body = '';
    };
}]);
```

I am currently running this skeleton by opening `index.html` in chromium.

Comment: Also had problems with that guide. What errors do you get?

Comment: what is your actual question?  Posting a mass of code and making a statement that it doesn't work doesn't exactly make this answerable...

Comment: and when you say you opened the index.html in chromium, do you mean that you went to `c:/mywebiste/index.html`, or `http://localhost/index.html`?  one will work, the other will probably not work.

Comment: @Claies Generally, you are correct. However, this one works fine without a local server instance. ;)

Comment: @kiswa which is why I said *probably*, though I didn't spend a lot of time analyzing the code to see what it was doing or where there might be syntax errors....

Comment: @Claies yes, it's just an Angular skeleton, but sorry about all the code ;)

Comment: kiswa, just out of curiosity why doesn't the comments page pop up when I run in jsbin or my browser with my file as the URL? Everything else works. http://snag.gy/rkeQz.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are typos in the app.js that will prevent it from working. In the future, open your browser's developer tools with the <kbd>F12</kbd> key and follow the links the errors provide to see what lines to change.

Specifically, there was an extra `;` and missing `,`s in a few places.

```js
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']);

app.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .state('posts', {
            url: '/posts/{id}',
            templateUrl: '/posts.html',
            controller: 'PostsCtrl'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}])

app.factory('posts', [function(){
    var o = {
        posts: []
    };
    return o;
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope',
'posts',
function($scope, posts){
    $scope.posts = posts.posts;
    $scope.addPost = function(){
        if(!$scope.theTitle || $scope.theTitle === '') { return; }
        $scope.posts.push({
            title: $scope.theTitle,
            link: $scope.theLink,
            upvotes: 0,
            comments: [
                {author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0},
                {author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 0}
            ]
        });
        $scope.theTitle = '';
        $scope.theLink = '';
    }
    $scope.upvote = function(post){
        post.upvotes++;
    }
}]);

app.controller('PostsCtrl', [
'$scope',
'$stateParams',
'posts',
function($scope, $stateParams, posts){
    $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];
    $scope.addComment = function(){
        if($scope.body === '') { return; }
        $scope.post.comments.push({
            body: $scope.body,
            author: 'user',
            upvotes: 0
        });
        $scope.body = '';
    };
}]);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flapper News</title>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <style> .glyphicon-thumbs-up { cursor:pointer } </style>
</head>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Flapper News</h1>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h3>
      <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
        {{post.title}}
      </a>
      <span ng-hide="post.link">
        {{post.title}}
      </span>
    </h3>
  </div>

  <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
      ng-click="incrementUpvotes(comment)"></span>
    {{comment.upvotes}} - by {{comment.author}}
    <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
      {{comment.body}}
    </span>
  </div>

 <form ng-submit="addComment()"
  style="margin-top:30px;">
  <h3>Add a new comment</h3>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="Comment"
    ng-model="body"></input>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
 </form>

</script>

<body ng-app="flapperNews" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <ui-view></ui-view>

            <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
                    ng-click="upvote(post)"></span>
                {{post.upvotes}}
                <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
                    <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
                        {{post.title}}
                    </a>
                    <span ng-hide="post.link">
                        {{post.title}}
                    </span>
                        <span>
                            <a href="#/posts/{{$index}}">Comments</a>
                        </span>
                </span>
            </div>

            <form ng-submit="addPost()"
                style="margin-top:30px;">
                <h3>Add a new post</h3>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Title"
                        ng-model="theTitle"></input>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Link"
                        ng-model="theLink"></input>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but the comment upvotes don't seem to work? **Edit:** haha nvm you guys rock :)

Comment: You're too new a user I think.

Comment: Oh, I meant on the Angular website. In jsbin and just by pasting the file link into chromium (file://path_to_file), I can't get the comments page to pop up like it does when I click your Run code snippet button. Sorry for the trouble, I know you're busy, do you have any ideas why?

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense.

Comment: Sorry I don't have enough rep to chat, but I edited a comment above, would you mind taking a look?

Comment: That would be one of those times when you want a local server running the site instead of just opening the file directly in your browser. The basic stuff works, but it breaks down once you try to do things that require server support.

Comment: Thanks so much! Last thing: Does this mean that I'm good to move onto the next section of the tutorial, the Node section?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is having issues with copying kiswa's code snippet, I found that moving the scripts just below the body element which has the ng-app solved the problem (currently they is sitting above the opening body tag).

So if you modify the code to look like this:

```
<!--code-->

</head>

<body ng-app="flapperNews" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Flapper News</h1>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>
            <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
                {{post.title}}
            </a>
      <span ng-hide="post.link">
        {{post.title}}
      </span>
        </h3>
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
          ng-click="incrementUpvotes(comment)"></span>
        {{comment.upvotes}} - by {{comment.author}}
    <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
      {{comment.body}}
    </span>
    </div>

    <form ng-submit="addComment()"
          style="margin-top:30px;">
        <h3>Add a new comment</h3>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text"
                   class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Comment"
                   ng-model="body"></input>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
    </form>

</script>

<!--rest of code-->
```

It should fix the issue. The reason is because the ng-app is defined in the body:

```
<body ng-app="flapperNews" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting it through a linter will go a long way.

Anyways,

Missing a comma here and have an extra semicolon:

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: '/home.html'  // <-- need a comma
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
});  // <-- remove this semicolon
.state('posts', {
    url: '/posts/{id}',
    templateUrl: '/posts.html',
    controller: 'PostsCtrl'
});
```

You need a comma after the upvotes value here:

```
$scope.posts.push({
    title: $scope.theTitle,
    link: $scope.theLink,
    upvotes: 0  // <-- need a comma
    comments: [
        {author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0},
        {author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 0}
    ]
});
```

This is also assuming that you are running through a local server and not just loading the `index.html` in a browser.  This fixed the issues in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hujazudulo/edit?html,js,output)