# Issues with use of $index within flapper news / mean-stack-tutorial

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/. I have done everything until the 'Beginning Node' section. So basically I have only the angularJS part, and not backend part. However, I am having issues with ui-routing already. I have added my items in app.js as such...

```
 posts: [
             { title: "Post 1", link: "#", upvotes: 5, comments: [] },
             { title: "Post 2", link: "#", upvotes: 2, comments: [] },
             { title: "Post 3", link: "#", upvotes: 5, comments: [] },
             { title: "Post 4", link: "#", upvotes: 9, comments: [] },
             { title: "Post 5", link: "#", upvotes: 4, comments: [] }
 ]
```

... but after the posts are ordered according to the number of `upvotes`...

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
```

... the original `$index` no longer seems to match. For instance, originally I added `Post 2` as item number two. But after the ordering, it displays as last because it has the fewest upvotes. Now, if I try to view the posts page by clicking on 'comments'... I see the wrong title. So if I click on 'comments' for 'Post 2', I see the title 'Post 5'... because after the ordering, 'Post 2' is the last item and angularJS tries to load the posts page for the last index, but it opens up the index from the original list hence 'Post 5'. Originally, I had expected the `$index` to be irrelevant since within app.js we are supposed to have wired the MainCtrl and PostsCtrl with the same service factory object. However, it turned out not to be the case.

Perhaps, I have just messed up somewhere, because this seems too much of a basic problem to have persisted in the tutorial for this long. Can somebody confirm that the tutorial is actually working.

ps - I understand that further on in the tutorial, once mongoDB is involved the tutorial will begin to use proper IDs instead of the `$index` and that should solve the problem... but still I want to know what am I doing wrong now. Thanks.

You can find the code to execute in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253487/thinkster-mean-stack-tutorial). Navigate down to the accepted answer and run the code/snippet to see what I mean.

Comment: If you want us to help you find bugs in your code and fix it, show us the code. All I can guess is that you need to replace `ng-click="show($index)"` with `ng-click="show(post)"`

Comment: I assumed you would take it from the tutorial link that I pasted. Please note that my question was actually asking someone to confirm that the tutorial code is working. So kindly copy everything from there until the 'Beginning Node' part. Much appreciated.

Comment: The code is supposed to be in the question. No, I won't dig into a several pages long tutorial and try guessing and finding the part that causes you a problem. That's your job. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*

Comment: @JBNizet Okay, I've added the code to the question. Kindly try it out. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Okay, I coming to the conclusion that my code is working fine, the tutorial just somehow screwed up on this particular point. I can't believe no one has pointed this out before. Someone, please prove me wrong. I would love to know what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having checked up on codes from other people following the same tutorial, I have come to the conclusion that I have followed the tutorial correctly. It's the code used within the tutorial itself that is causing this behavior. In fact, until you complete the tutorial following the back end as well (i.e. beginning node)... the angularJS part in itself does not even manage to show the correct list of comments once you have changed the index, by increasing the upvotes.